# Where to ask about implementations of WS-* standards?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

To avoid deletion in the future, questions that might lead to opinionated answers, with multiple good solutions like:

> I recently started to read about SAGA pattern in the context of
>   distributed transactions for microservices and found out that is
>   actually an old concept that inspired the WS-* specs , more concretely
>   WS-Reliable Messaging,WS-AtomicTransaction, WS-Coordination, and
>   WS-BusinessActivity.
>
> I searched for some concrete samples to understand better these
>   standards but despite their latest update in 2009 OASIS I did not
>   found much.
>
> Do you know some implementation of the above mentioned WS standards?
>
> Are they still actual as I mentioned before last update was like 10
>   years ago...?

Is there a site where I can ask the above question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a question like you propose would be too broad for most, probably all, Stack Exchange sites because it is effectively asking multiple questions.

Your question is effectively asking:

- Do you know some implementation of the WS-Reliable Messaging standard?
- Do you know some implementation of the WS-AtomicTransaction standard?
- Do you know some implementation of the WS-Coordination standard?
- Do you know some implementation of the WS-BusinessActivity?

and also:

- Is each still a current specification?

You could probably ask your question as-is in a chat room, but I am unfamiliar with the topic you are asking about, and cannot advise which.

A quick search reveals that [Stack Overflow has questions tagged ws-reliablemessaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ws-reliablemessaging) so if you can address your question scope issues, and focus each of your embedded questions, then you may be able to ask them there.

Comment: So, is there a solution? Perhaps, breaking it up into multiple questions? If so, would those be on topic anywhere?

Comment: @Catija I think it being clearly multiple questions is the first problem.  The next is that each of the first four that I broke it up into may be seeking a list of implementations, and the last one could be asked for each of the four specifications.  In other words, the question as posed needs considerable work before it is suitable for focused Q&A.